# How to change AndroidManifest during build in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.android

Is there a way to change generated AndroidManifest during the build in Xamarin?

Generated manifest in directory in \obj\Release\120\android has /service android:name="crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseMessagingService"/ and I nned to add android:exported="true" property to after the file is generated before it is included in build.

I cannot upgrade the dll with PNFirebaseMessagingService to never version, where the exported flag is set correctly :-(
Thanks for any ideas.

I tried to add /service android:name="crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true"/ to the Properties/AndroidManifest but i got error APT2263: unexpected element service found in manifest.

Comment: The android app is built according to the AndroidManifest.xml, so you can't change it during build. It seems a service registered by the firebase packages, why you need to add it?